# How to add Korean as the 2nd IME to elemetaryOS Juno with Japanese IME?

Tags: elementary-os, input-method, fcitx

I want to add a Korean input method on an elementary OS Juno system which currently running `fcitx-mozc` with a US-101 keyboard. Because of some business restrictions, I cannot freely sacrifice `Mozc` only for a Korean IME or switch from `fcitx` to `iBus`.

The current steps I have done is the following: I installed `fcitx-hangul` through APT command. I opened `fcitx-config-gtk3` menu, added a `Keyboard-Korean` option from the list, and did logout/in. It still toggles English<->Japanese fine. But, no signs for Korean input options show up.

Is there any way I can switch those 3 languages on `fcitx` with minimal environmental changes or additions? I am aiming at a goal that can enable Japanese IME by hitting left-CTRL + SPACE, and enable Korean IME by right-CTRL + SPACE (or some other short-cut key).

Any suggestions. Or, what process am I missing?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a way to toggle over 3 language modes with one shortcut key; however, I found the closest answer to my question.

Hit CTRL + SPACE to activate IME with the last mode (Japanese/Korean) or deactivate IME.
When IME is activated, hit CTRL + SHIFT to toggle between Japanese and Korean.

It seems working fine with this way :)